# How to hide a Gravity Forms field with css

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, gravity-forms-plugin, wordpress

I would like to hide one of the fields (product field) entirely using CSS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use the `gf_invisible` class on the "CSS Class Name" setting for the field. This class is available out of the box with Gravity Forms and hides the field by positioning it off the screen rather than "display: none;. Gravity Forms will not count product fields that are "display: none;" towards the total.

More information here: http://gravitywiz.com/how-to-hide-gravity-forms-product-fields/

Comment: Seems rather roundabout. Why even have the hidden type if it isn't going to count toward the total...

Comment: The Hidden product type does count towards the total. I assumed the OP was asking about non-Hidden product fields since he wanted to hide the field via CSS.

Comment: Maybe a bug in a recent Gravity Forms, but I ran into one that didn't count when I changed it to hidden. This got around it so I probably won't bother debugging

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Custom CSS Class via the Appearance tab of the field (for example 'hide-field'. Than in css you add:

`.hide-field{
    display: none;
}`

Comment: This will prevent the field from being counted toward the total. See @David's answer